# using interface as indexer

Tags: c#, interface

I have a question regarding interfaces in c#.
Currently I am doing an internship and came across the following code:

```
namespace MyNote
{
public interface INote
{
    double Time { get; set; }
    String Text { get; }
}

public class Note : INote
{
    private double _time;
    private String _text;

    public Note(double time, String text)
    {
        _time = time;
        _text = text;
    }

    public double Time
    {
        get
        {
            return _time;
        }
        set
        {
            _time = value;
        }
    }

    public String Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _text;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The question:
What is the use of this interface? Nobody can answer my question so maybe you guys.

Comment: Are there any other classes implementing `INote`? Is `INote` used as type somehwere?

Comment: Nobody in your company knows? You should look for references to `INote` and that should answer your question. There must be a method or something that expects a class that implements that interface, and that `Note` class is just one of them.

Comment: For a general info about the usefulness of interfaces: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/108240/why-are-interfaces-useful

Comment: But what is the exact difference in intantiating an interface or a class. The program makes use of a list filled with Inote, but it could have just been Note couldn't it. In my opinion it's not really all that different.

Answer (score 1):

The main use of interface is code re-usability and to replace multiple inheritance.

You may want to have a look on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b5b8ezk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [this](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/c-interfaces-what-are-they-and)